# Designing class from JSON strings

Tags: java

I am designing a class using the below JSON string. I am later going to use GSON to read the JSON string. I am having trouble designing the class. I have tried way too many version, but none are returning the desired results. Clearly, I am not designing the class correctly. My application code is very complex, so I can't paste that here. I just need help in figuring out my class' design as I have tried way too many times without success. Please go easy on me since I am extremely new to Java. Please.

JSON String:

```
    {"info": [{"name":"Cineplex Outlets","storeCode":"3001","deptID":"5630","location":"Singapore","geography":"East","team_number":"Team 9",
"country":"United States","state":"Arizona","city":"Phoenix","address":{"storeAdd":["123,East Park St","1811 Fountain View","Pheoniz, 
Arizona, 91210","United States"]},"passcode":"1001","telephone":{"landline":"1-818-502 8310"},"operationTimings":{"Monday":"10:00AM - 9:00PM",
"Tuesday":"10:00AM - 9:00PM","Friday":"10:00AM - 9:00PM","Wednesday":"10:00AM - 9:00PM","Thursday":"10:00AM - 9:00PM","Sunday":"11:00AM - 7:00PM",
"Saturday":"10:00AM - 9:00PM"},"links":{"myStInfo":"http://www.xyz","appointments":"http://abc",
"directions":"http://pqr"},"picture":{"http":"http://azy","https":"https://bbj"}}
```

Java Class:

```
public class MyClass {
  private String name;
  private String storeCode;
  private Long deptID;
  private String location;
  private String geography;
  private String team_number;
  private String country;
  private String state;
  private String city;
  private Address address;


public static class MyClassTest
{
    private ArrayList<MyClass> info;    
    private String passcode;
    private Telephone telephone;
    private Hours operationTimings;
    private StoreUrl links;
    private StoreImage picture; 
}


public static class Address
{
    private ArrayList<String> storeAdd;
}

public static class Telephone
{
    private String telephone;
}

public static class Hours
{
    private String Monday;
    private String Tuesday;
    private String Friday;
    private String Wednesday;
    private String Thursday;
    private String Sunday;
    private String Saturday;
}

public static class StoreUrl
{
    private URL myStInfo;
    private URL appointments;
    private URL directions;
}


public static class StoreImage
{
    private URL http;
    private URL https;
}

}
```

Comment: Priya, I hope you find yourself solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A property name of class Telephone is **landline**, not *telephone*. Principal class T1, has only one property, *info*, and is an array of String. You miss in Json string "]}".

```
   public class T1
{
    public ArrayList<T2> info;
}

public class T2
{
    public String name;
    public String storeCode;  
    public String deptID;    
    public String location;
    public String geography;
    public String team_number;
    public String country;
    public String state;
    public String city;
    public Address address;
    public String passcode;
    public Telephone telephone;
    public OperationTime operationTimings;
    public Links links;
    public Picture picture;
}

public class Address 
{
    public ArrayList<String> storeAdd;
}

public class Telephone 
{
    public String landline;
}

public class OperationTime 
{
    public String Monday;
    public String Tuesday;
    public String Friday;
    public String Wednesday;
    public String Thursday;
    public String Sunday;
    public String Saturday;
}

public class Links
{
    public String myStInfo;
    public String appointments;
    public String directions;
}

public class Picture
{
    public String http;
    public String https;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Does everything else look okay?

Comment: I will send another model of classes because there are son problems.

Comment: Some libraries to convert Json, take the properties alphabetically, keep this in mind. The main class T1 (in your case, MyClassTest), only contains the property "info", properties passcode, telephone, operationTimings, links and picture are of T2 class, not the class MyClass.